# Can't get QField Sync to export projects with correct Layer path

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I work with QGIS 3.22 on Debian bookworm. Since I want to collect data in the field, I have installed QField 3.1.3 on my smartphone and the QField Sync 4.6.3 extension in QGIS.
I was able to successfully pack my first test project consisting of an orthophoto and two point shapes with QField Sync and then import it into QField. However, all further attempts to import project folders created with QField Sync failed because QField is not able to find the layers. I took a look at the exported .qgs files and noticed that the path to the layers is apparently saved incorrectly in the .qgs file by QField Sync from the second export onwards. During the first export, the tag `<datasource>` was created like this:

`<datasource>./testshape.shp</datasource>`

For all subsequent exports, it looks like this:

`<datasource>../testproject/testshape.shp</datasource>`

I have just installed QGIS 3.28.13 from the backports as a test. As a result, I was able to perform an error-free export once again, but all further exports then lead to the wrong path specification again.

Why does QField Sync suddenly no longer save the relative path name after the first successful use, but the path to the original QGIS project folder which only exists on my PC but not on my smartphone?  The use of relative path names is still activated in the QGIS project.

Update: Today I updated to 3.28.14 from the bookworm-backports repository. Following the update, I was able to export the project once without errors. After a restart, the export again resulted in an incorrect path (see above).

Can anyone perhaps reproduce this?